# How to control docker-compose build order?

Tags: docker, docker-compose

I have three services to build, A、B and C. A should be built in the very first place, because B and C depend on A (they import A as image). I thought they should be built in order but I just find out they are built in some random order?

So, how do I control build order in `docker-compose.yml`?

Comment: Looking for some added clarity, are you talking about `docker-compose build` to build images or are you talking about `docker-compose up -d` to build/run containers?

Comment: Not certain it changes much, but I may ask a different question/reference this one, or propose to add/edit some wording and either add a bounty or do some digging on my own depending on which is being referenced.

Comment: Please check [this solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51425060/4728425). It works for me

Answer (score 21):

The accepted answer above does not seem correct.

As seen in the [documentation](https://docs.docker.com/compose/compose-file/#depends_on)

> There are several things to be aware of when using depends_on:
>
> **depends_on does not wait for db and redis to be “ready” before
>   starting web - only until they have been started.** If you need to wait
>   for a service to be ready, see Controlling startup order for more on
>   this problem and strategies for solving it.
>
> Version 3 no longer supports the condition form of depends_on.
>
> The depends_on option is ignored when deploying a stack in swarm mode
>   with a version 3 Compose file.

Comment: Did you test it;) Actually, `depends_on` **affects the build** stage, I tested this just now.

Comment: I think this answer actually makes sense in part, I have encountered a problem that stems from this particular piece of docs - one of my containers can be built only after the other one is running. This is what is meant by "depends_on does not wait for db and redis to be “ready” before starting web". However, disagreeing with the accepted answer is incorrect. OP asked about controlling build order and nothing more, whereas this comment talks about container run order.

Comment: more specifically it's about not being able to sync what happens after both once containers have started

Comment: @maxkoryukov according to docker-compose [using `depends_on` within the context of `docker-compose build` not an intended use](https://github.com/docker/compose/issues/6332#issuecomment-437143989). I agree, it appears to affect the build stage, but it's not a guarantee.

Comment: @ArthurWeborg there are enough changes in the Docker and Docker Compose (since I wrote the first comment) and the latest versions support the [_multistage build_](https://docs.docker.com/develop/develop-images/multistage-build/). This feature solved a lot of problems; at least, I stopped to use `depends_on` for building custom images from the same *base* image.

Comment: @maxkoryukov, can you elaborate? Can the multistage build affect run order too?

Comment: @QuintenScheppermans **no**, multi-stage build affects only building process, not run-order.

Comment: @maxkoryukov Are multistage builds a solution to the question here? I don't think you can tag multiple images from one build.

Answer (score 15):

> **Update:**
>   In recent practice, I have found my answer to only pertain to run ordering.
>   Refer to the answer by Quinten Scheppermans and the comment by Authur Weborg about *dobi*.

You can control build order using [`depends_on`](https://docs.docker.com/compose/compose-file/#depends_on) directive.

```
services:
  ...

  B:
    depends_on:
      - A
  C:
    depends_on:
      - A
```

Comment: Does `depends_on` have effect on building phase? I had a peek on [documents](https://docs.docker.com/compose/compose-file/#depends_on) and it seems only have effect on starting phase.

Comment: Yes it does. Not sure why it isn't documented

Comment: You can also use `links`, `net`, `volume_from` to influence build priority

Comment: I reached out to docker-compose on github. Their response was that [`depends_on` is not an intended use with docker-compose build](https://github.com/docker/compose/issues/6332#issuecomment-437143989)

Comment: Thanks for letting me know that. I didn't about know `dobi`. There was the behavior of ordered builds for services based on the service dependency if I remember correctly; as you point out this has changed and only pertains to ordered runs. I'll edit the answer to reference your comment.

Comment: You're welcome, I didn't either, I was rather bummed when their response was I was miss-using the depends_on syntax :( Thanks for updating!

Comment: In most cases, the [**multistage build**](https://docs.docker.com/develop/develop-images/multistage-build/) is more appropriate.

Comment: The above answer does not seem accurate as per documentation, see 
Quinten Scheppermans answer

Comment: Yeah this answer is wrong. It absolutely doesn't work with the depends_on directive.

Answer (score 4):

Since compose v2, [BuildKit](https://docs.docker.com/develop/develop-images/build_enhancements/) is enabled by default, it will build images parallelly.

By [disabling BuildKit](https://docs.docker.com/develop/develop-images/build_enhancements/#to-enable-buildkit-builds) you get to build images according to the order in your `docker-compose.yml` file.

```
DOCKER_BUILDKIT=0 docker-compose build
```

If you still want to build images parallelly, you can consider defining `services` in multiple `docker-compose.yml` files for building, then composing up in another `docker-compose.yml` file for deployment.

Answer (score 3):

If you need to run one service before an other you can use `docker-compose run bar` after setting `depends_on: - foo`  in your docker-compose.yml file.

For example:

```
# docker-compose.yml

  services:
    foo:
        . . . 
    bar:
         . . . 
      depends_on:
        - foo
```

then run,

```
# terminal

user@Name Docker % docker-compose run bar
```

However, per the [docs](https://docs.docker.com/compose/startup-order/), this will only control the order in which processes start, not the order in which they finish. This can often lead to situations in which dependent services do not properly start. Potential solutions for this include using [wait-for-it](https://github.com/vishnubob/wait-for-it), [wait-for](https://github.com/Eficode/wait-for), or [Dockerise](https://github.com/jwilder/dockerize). I recommend reading the [docs](https://docs.docker.com/compose/startup-order/) before implementing any of the solutions listed above, as there are caveats.

Answer (score 0):

As stated in https://github.com/docker/compose/blob/e9220f45df07c1f884d5d496507778d2cd4a1687/compose/project.py#L182-L183

> Preserves the original order of self.services where possible, reordering as needed to resolve dependencies.

So for me it worked by manually sorting the services with the depending services at first and following the services which is used by the other and the other as last.

**Example**

```
version: '3'
services:
    mydb:
        image: mydb
    serviceA:
        build: 
            dockerfile: DockerfileA
        depends_on:
            - mydb
    serviceB:
        build:
            dockerfile: DockerfileB # which contains 'FROM serviceA'
        depends_on:
            - mydb
```

Source: https://github.com/docker/compose/issues/5228#issuecomment-565469948

Comment: This doesn't work anymore since builds are run in parallel