# Can we start the containers before building the multiple images with in a same docker-compose.yaml?

Tags: docker, docker-compose

I did write docker-compose.yaml for two services named as MySQL and JasperReports. I wrote the docker files for each service. while executing the docker-compose using `docker-compose up -d`, first it starts building the images for both the services, after that, running the containers based on the mentioned dependency level. but I have the requirement that Mysql service image will have to build first and run the container after that jasper server image will have to build and start running the container. Does it possible using docker-compose? why because jasper server uses the MySQL port and host. so, how cloud I achieve this case?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to control docker-compose build order?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46295806/how-to-control-docker-compose-build-order)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As explained in the docker-compose docs in [Control startup and shutdown order in Compose](https://docs.docker.com/compose/startup-order/), you may write a custom shell script that waits for mysql to be ready (i.e.  accepting connections), before starting the jasper service.