# Aerospike docker connection refused using docker servicename

Tags: python, docker, aerospike

I am trying to use aerospike docker container , with python application also running same docker network. Below is the docker compose file.

```
aerospike:
    image: aerospike/aerospike-server
    volumes: 
      - "./aerospikeconfig:/opt/aerospike/etc"
    environment: 
      config-file: /opt/aerospike/etc/aerospike.conf

  rtbconsumer:
    image: abhinav054/rtb_consumer:trending
    depends_on: 
      - aerospike
      - kafka
    environment: 
      CONSUMER_ID: "rtb_aerospike_2"
      HOST: "kafka:9092"
      TOPIC: "rtb-logs"
      AEROSPIKE_HOST: "aerospike:3000"
```

So in my script I am connecting aerospike using the below given config

```
config = { 
      'hosts':[('aerospike', 3000)],
      'policies': {
        'timeout': 1000 # milliseconds
      }
    }
```

The error I am getting is **exception.ConnectionError: (-10, 'Failed to connect', 'src/main/aerospike/as_cluster.c', 254, False)**

Can someone please help me figure out the problem.

Comment: You need to specify a bridge network in de compose-file. it's not enough for them to run on the same host.

Comment: @QuintenScheppermans ain't the default network bridge, I am a bit rusty on the networking. Can you send some sample.

Comment: You could also create an overlay network that could be used for clustering or connections between services. https://discuss.aerospike.com/t/faq-aerospike-on-docker/6520

Answer (score 1):

You could try creating an [overlay network](https://docs.docker.com/network/overlay/) in your docker-compose and adjust your aerospike.conf interface address bindings accordingly.
Aerospike repo has an example using [docker swam](https://github.com/aerospike/aerospike-docker-swarm).

```
  aerospike:
    image: aerospike/aerospike-server
    volumes: 
      - "./aerospikeconfig:/opt/aerospike/etc"
    environment: 
      config-file: /opt/aerospike/etc/aerospike.conf
    networks:
      - aerospikenet

  rtbconsumer:
    image: abhinav054/rtb_consumer:trending
    depends_on: 
      - aerospike
      - kafka
    environment: 
      CONSUMER_ID: "rtb_aerospike_2"
      HOST: "kafka:9092"
      TOPIC: "rtb-logs"
      AEROSPIKE_HOST: "aerospike:3000"
    networks:
      - aerospikenet

networks:
    aerospikenet:
        driver: overlay  #used on multiple host configurations
       #driver: bridge   #used on single host configuration
        attachable: true
```

Comment: I am not planning to use docker swarm, and I just want it to work on normal docker network.

Comment: I am running all the containers on the same host, technically there should not be a problem regarding the overlay docker network.

Comment: Switching driver type from overlay to bridge as mentioned by QuintenScheppermans should work in your case of a single host. https://docs.docker.com/compose/compose-file/compose-file-v2/#network-configuration-reference

Answer (score 1):

In response to your question, which should also solve your problem:

> @QuintenScheppermans ain't the default network bridge, I am a bit rusty on the networking. Can you send some sample.

Yes, containers are automatically added to a default bridge network. However, Docker does not support automatic service discovery on the default bridge network. If you want containers to be able **to resolve IP addresses by container name**, you should use user-defined networks instead.

This is exactly what you're doing here:

```
config = { 
  'hosts':[('aerospike', 3000)],
  'policies': {
    'timeout': 1000 # milliseconds
  }
}
```

So you do need to configure a user-defined network.
**Bridge networks** are recommended for single host networks (like in your case)
Overlay networks are recommended for multiple host networks.

You can use Ivolmar's answer and switch it to a bridge network.
You don't need to use docker swarm if you don't want that.

Comment: I am using docker-compose, which creates a default names bridge network, similar to user-defined networks. I don't think this will help. I think there is an issue with aerospike, it is not resolving it properly. Let me read the aerospike documentation.

Comment: Can you ping one container from within the other container (by servicename)? It's clearly stated in the official docker documentation for networking (https://docs.docker.com/v17.09/engine/userguide/networking/#the-default-bridge-network). I can't find anything about docker-compose behaving differently. But I might be wrong.

Comment: Unfortunately, yes I am able to establish the tcp connection, that's why I am starting to think it has to be an aerospike issue.

Comment: Something else maybe. What if you run the Aerospike container first (make sure aerospike is actually running) and then boot your other container. depends_on only controls build order, not run order. So if Aerospike takes a while to start up, your other container could crash.

Comment: rtbconsumer:
    depends_on: 
      - aerospike
      - kafka
I have already added the depends on statement. Doesn't work ...

Comment: As I said, depends_on controls build order of the image, not what's running within the image. Look at my answer on this post: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46295806/how-to-control-docker-compose-build-order/50129784#50129784